# GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:27:14.210: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed when initializing structure within Qt Project

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to use `libgerbv` from the Gerbv-Project within my Qt-Application to render some Gerber files.
As soon as I try to create the gerbv_project_t structure, the application crashes immediately when run giving the following errors:

```
(libgerbv-test:31719): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 14:36:57.579: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplayManager'

(libgerbv-test:31719): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:36:57.579: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(libgerbv-test:31719): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 14:36:57.579: g_object_new_with_properties: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
```

As far as I could find out, these errors are usually related to gtk-framework errors which really makes no sense to me: apart from the gtk headers being included by the `gerbv.h`-header, I don't use any of the gtk-related stuff. I don't get why it seems to try to register with some GdkDisplayManager?

I am unfortunately completely lost at this point, any help is greatly appreciated!

These are my files

**libgerbv-test.pro**:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11 link_pkgconfig

DEFINES += QT_NO_KEYWORDS    #Workaround for "expected unqualified-id before"-error

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

PKGCONFIG += libgerbv cairo pixman-1
```

**mainwindow.h**:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "gerbv.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

protected:

    gerbv_project_t *mainProject;

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "gerbv.h"
#include "cairo.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    mainProject = gerbv_create_project();      // <-- This seems to be the critical line

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.ui**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar"/>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: I found that adding the line
`gtk_init(nullptr, nullptr);`
in `main` makes the error disappear and as far as I could test by now, everything seems to work fine using this workaround. However I came to this solution by reading a comment within the constructor of the file `qgtk3theme.cpp` included with Qt and just giving it a try. To be very honest, I was surprised this actually worked and I don't really understand how. So if someone could explain what goes on here that is still greatly appreciated. For now I don't consider this a solution, but rather a dirty workaround.